# YouTube API. How to get approximate quantity of results?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am interested in number which represents approximate number of results for some defined search parameters. It is presented on the picture below as "About N results".

Is it possible to get this somehow?
[image]
PS. I am using Java for android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Videos.search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)  returns a response body which looks like this.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "regionCode": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    search Resource
  ]
}
```

I think the closest you are going to get is going to be totalResults.  Which I really doubt will be that large.

I just did a dummy search with basically asking for everything and it returned

```
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
```

The max rows you will get back from a search from the API is 1000000 google is not going to tell you how much a search on the website would return.  So the answer to your question is there is no way to return the actual value the website would return via the API.

Comment: Do this dummy search several times with different q-parameter and you will understand that this number doesn't change. Because this number represents allowed for api users results. But the real number is different. Compare this "dummy" result with real youtube search, and you will find that numbers are different!!!

Comment: Exactly and the API is not going to give you back what the true YouTbue website Search will.

Comment: @DalmTo so, you are saying that this is not possible?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying